# Function template with pointers inside

Tags: c++, templates, typename

I have the following function which creates a 2D array

```
double** createMatrix(int r, int c)
{
    double** matrix = (double**)malloc(r * sizeof(double*));
    if (matrix) {
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            matrix[i] = (double*)malloc(c * sizeof(double));
            if (matrix[i]) {}
            else {
                printf("Memory not allocated.\n");
                free(matrix[i]);
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Memory not allocated.\n");
        free(matrix);
        exit(0);
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

I want to define a template for this function allowing it to create a matrix of generic type but this seems not working:

```
template <typename T>
T** createMatrix(int r, int c)
{
    T** matrix = (T**)malloc(r * sizeof(T*));
    if (matrix) {
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            matrix[i] = (T*)malloc(c * sizeof(T));
            if (matrix[i]) {}
            else {
                printf("Memory not allocated.\n");
                free(matrix[i]);
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Memory not allocated.\n");
        free(matrix);
        exit(0);
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

where is the problem?

Comment: When you state "... but this seems not working", please clarify what you mean. In particular, how are you trying to use that template function, do you get a compiler error, the results are not correct, etc.?

Comment: it is working fine [online example](https://godbolt.org/z/vj1x5vMrW).

Comment: oh right, you need to place your function definition in the header now that it is a templated function, you can no-longer put it in the cpp file.

Comment: I changed the header file accordingly but i get a compilation error

Comment: @D.Alfano [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77892966/edit), copy and paste the error into the question.

Comment: Sorry but I use Visual Studio in italian. I'm trying to change language to show you the error i get but I don't know how to do it. However i forgotten to specify <double> when I call the function but even if i specify the type it doesn't compile. I think the problem could be in the linkage

Comment: I put the function in a separate file and "template <typename T>
T** createMatrix(int r, int c);" in the header

Comment: the function body itself goes into the header, all the snippet in the question must be in the header.

Comment: Ok, i didn't know, sorry. So i cannot have a .c file and a .h file for functions like this? I must have only a .h file?

Comment: yes, only .h file, that's why you have a lot of header-only libraries in C++.

Comment: @D.Alfano Function templates should be implemented in header file. See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)